# show random image on Processing

Tags: image, random, processing, show

I'm really noob on processing and programing and I can't figure it out how to show my images at random.

I'm loading the images in setup with the PImage name img0, img1, img2 and then

```java
image("img" + random(3), 0, 0);
```

But it does't work, coz processing wait for a PImage argument, and the string plus a number isn't.

And I know for shure there must be some better way than:

```java
int randomNumber = random(3);

if(randomNumber == 0 ){ 
   image(img0,0,0);
} 
if(randomNumber == 1 ){ 
    image(img1,0,0);
} 
if(randomNumber == 2 ){
    image(img2,0,0);
}
```

But I haven't found it.

Any thoughts?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Kevin's great answer you can also use a an array to store the loaded PImages.

Here's a rough example (you'll need to adjust path to images of course):

```
// total number of images
int numImages = 3;
// an array of images
PImage[] images = new PImage[num];

int randomNumber;

void setup(){
    //TODO correct sketch size
    size(300,300);
    // initialize images array (loading each one)
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numImages; i++){
        // TODO correct path to images
        images[i] = loadImage("img"+(i)+".png");
    }
}
void draw(){
    background(0);
    //render the most recently selected random index image
    image(images[randomNumber]);
    //instructions
    text("click to randomize",10,15);
}
// change the random number on click (draw() would look chaotic/hard to debug)
void mousePressed(){
    // pick a random number and cast the floating point value return to integer needed as in images array index
    randomNumber = (int)random(numImages);
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. My answer assumes you care about the "stringy" part of the variable name, which probably doesn't actually matter. Nice one.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `HashMap` to create a map from `String` keys to `PImage` values. Something like this:

```
HashMap<String, PImage> imageMap = new HashMap<String, PImage>();
imageMap.put("image1", image1);
imageMap.put("image2", image2);
```

Then to get a `PImage` from a `String` key, you'd call the `get()` function:

```
PImage image1 = imageMap.get("image1");
```

You can find more info in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/HashMap.html).

By the way, this line won't compile:

```
int randomNumber = random(3);
```

The `random()` function returns a `float` value. You can't store a `float` value in an `int` variable. You have to convert it using the `int()` function:

```
int randomNumber = int(random(3));
```

If you still can't get it working, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. Good luck.